# Регулярное выражение для поиска соответствия некорректной записи С++

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, qt, pcre

Реализую строковый калькулятор, где у меня есть этап, на котором я перед вычислением выражения делаю проверку на валидность выражения.

Для поиска использую язык С++, PCRE

```
bool Calculation::expression_validate(QString& infix) {
  QVector<QRegularExpression> regex{
      QRegularExpression(".(?<![+\\-*\\/^(.]|mod|\\d)(\\d)"),
      QRegularExpression("(?<![)x]|\\d)([\\*\\/^]|mod)"),
      QRegularExpression("(?<![)x]|\\d)([+\\-\\*\\/^]|mod)([+-])"),
      QRegularExpression("(?<![())x+\\-\\*\\/^]|\\d|mod)([+-])"),
      QRegularExpression(".(?<![+\\-*\\/^(a]|mod)(a?(cos|sin|tan)|sqrt|ln)"),
      QRegularExpression(".(?<![+\\-*\\/^(sntgd])[(]"),
      QRegularExpression("(?<!\\d|[)]|x)[)]"),
      QRegularExpression("\\d*?[.]\\d*?[.]\\d*?"),
      QRegularExpression(".(?<!\\d|[\\)x])$")};
  bool check = true;
  for (auto it : regex) {
    if (infix.contains(it)) {
      check = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return check;
}
```

Калькулятор работает с простыми операциями как `[+-*/^]|mod`, так и тригонометрическими функциями `cos|sin|tan|acos|asin|atan|ln|log + sqrt`

Обработка всех сочетаний использования операторов, функций и цифр, а также `x`

```
cos(5+1.34^6--ln(2.71))
(((((((-5))))))))
-x^2^(1/cos(1))
```

*Вопрос в следующем: каким образом переписать регулярные выражения на так называемый правильный вид, чтобы избавится от костылей как в следующем выражении?*

```
                 ->|.            ->|a
QRegularExpression(".(?<![+\\-*\\/^(a]|mod)(a?(cos|sin|tan)|sqrt|ln)")
```

[(выражение)](https://regex101.com/r/qiwmPL/3)

В данном выражении обрабатываются функции, перед которыми не должно быть след.символов `[+\\-*\\/^(a]`:

1. Первая проблема в том, что запись без `.` and `a` в выражении `5+acos(1)` найдёт сравнение `cos`, перед которым `a`, которое не входит в список значений на сравнение.
2. Обработка в начале строки данного выражения находит `null`, для обхода этого стоит костыль на любой символ для избежания проверки в начале строки.

Также завершающим этапом проверки является проверка на валидность по скобочкам, в какой они последовательности, и их количество, на просторах интернета нашёл рег.выражение:

```
^[^()\n]*+(\((?>[^()\n]|(?1))*+\)[^()\n]*+)++$
```

*Вопрос в следующем: каким образом переписать его, чтобы та находила противоположные значения, отличные от верных?*

Comment: Может быть попробуете прочитать в метке [регулярные-выражения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/info) как задать вопрос. Я честно пытаюсь понять что вам нужно, но не могу))

Comment: Попробуйте ``(?<=^|[-+*\/^(]|mod)(ln|log|sqrt|a?(cos|sin|tan))(*SKIP)(*F)|(?1)``

Comment: Во втором случае попробуйте ``(\((?>[^()\n]|(?1))*+\))(*SKIP)(*F)|[()]``

Comment: Зачем?! У вас же должен быть парсер выражений, который преобразует их в префиксную нотацию или что-то такое. Вот пусть он и ищет ошибки.